# ASP.NET MVC - Can a Partial View have a controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.renderpartial

When I'm in a View and I call `@Html.RenderPartial("MyPartialView", MyObject)`  Can I set it up so that this partial view has a controller which is called when RenderPartial gets called?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably it will be better to use the [RenderAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction.aspx) instead of the **RenderPartial**

Comment: Yes. It looks like I need to use RenderAction instead. Also found this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968664/asp-net-mvc-2-0-difference-between-renderpartial-and-renderaction

Answer (score 1):

You should gather all data necessary for the partial in the current controller action (which may use methods shared across other controllers and actions).

If you really want a partial to be rendered using its own controller/action then consider loading it via AJAX with a separate request.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, although controllers know about views, the reverse is not true.

Views are just means to render some data (a model or a viewModel) but they are not related to a controller or an action.