# DevExpress tabs and gridview inside

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress, renderaction

How to call controller and its action from PartialPage.cshtml 
Let say I have

```
Html.DevExpress().PageControl(
        settings =>
        {
            settings.Name = "MyTabs";
            settings.Width = 520;
            settings.Height = 360;
            settings.ActivateTabPageAction = ActivateTabPageAction.Click;
            settings.EnableHotTrack = true;
            settings.SaveStateToCookies = true;
            settings.TabAlign = TabAlign.Left;
            settings.TabPosition = TabPosition.Top;

            settings.TabPages.Add("Houses").SetContent(() =>
            {
                Html.Render("_RenderTabHousesPartial", Model);
            });
            settings.TabPages.Add("Apartments").SetContent(() =>
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("_TabApartmentsPartial", Model);
            });
        }).GetHtml()
```

Now I want to replace this Html.RenderPartial("_TabApartmentsPartial", Model); with call controller which will return me some data in this section

```
settings.TabPages.Add("Houses").SetContent(() =>
{
   /Controller/Action/
});
```

That controller will be responsible to return me partialView with some data.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Possible Duplicate:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588571/asp-net-mvc-can-a-partial-view-have-a-controller/6588723#6588723)

Use the **[RenderAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction.aspx)** instead of the **RenderPartial**:

```
settings.TabPages.Add("Houses").SetContent(() => {
   Html.RenderAction(...);
});
```

Comment: I tried with   settings.TabPages.Add("Houses").SetContent(() =>
                {
                    Html.RenderAction<HomeController>(x => x.TabHousesPartial()); 
                });
                If I understood correctly controller name should be as a first parameter and x=>x. as action method.

Comment: Yes, see the [ChildActionExtensions.RenderAction Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721274.aspx) article where you can find a sample